# Integral $\int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^\infty_{-\infty}(\frac{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}{s_1^2}+1)^{-a_1-1}(\frac{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}{s_2^2}+1)^{-a_2-1}dxdy$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

Under $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb R$, $s_i>0$ and $a_i>0$ for $i=1,2$, is there any good function to express the following integral?
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^\infty_{-\infty}
\left(\frac{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}{s_1^2}+1\right)^{-a_1-1}
\left(\frac{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}{s_2^2}+1\right)^{-a_2-1}dxdy$$

Comment: You have $\large\left(y - y_{2}\right)$ in both terms. Isn't $\large y_{1}$ in the first one ?.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! Now it's corrected.